# Periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

Its system of ode:

$$\left\{
        \begin{array}{l}
            x' = x(1 -\frac{x}{k}) - \frac{dxy}{1+x} \\
            y' = -my + \frac{dxy}{1+x}
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

I found 3  equilibriums:

- $(0,0)$ (*saddle*)
- $(k,0)$ (*saddle*) and
- $\left(\frac{m}{d-m}, \frac{m(kd - mk - m)}{(d-m)^2  km }\right)$, if $\frac{m}{d-m} < \frac{k-1}{2}$ is stable, is not stable in opposite situation.

How can i show that if $\frac{m}{d-m} < \frac{k-1}{2}$, the periodic solution exists?

Comment: Too  many parameters to consider. Perhaps choosing one or two of them will facilitate the precise answer.